# spring mvc response not loading in jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following jQuery ajax code:

```
<script>

    $(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url : "signin.html",
                type : "post",
                cache: false,
                data : "userName=" +$("#userName").val()+ '&password='+$("#password").val(),
                success : function(data) {
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    var msg = '<span>' + obj.message + '</span>';
                    $('#message').html(msg);
                },
             //EDIT
    error: function(){                      
        alert('Error in response...');
    }
            });
        });
    });
</script>


<div id="message"></div>
```

I have spring controller which sends message as responses which I am trying to print in the message box. I see the request processed by the controller but the message from the controller is not getting displayed in the page. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView loginUser(request attributes here){

            isUserExisits = service.authenticateUser(userBO);
            if (isUserExisits) {
                model.addObject("message", "Login Success");
            } else {
                model.addObject("message", "Login Failed");
            }}
```

EDIT:- I have added error callback after 'success' and error call back function is getting called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a `ModelAndView` object and accessing a property which does not exist in `ModelAndView` class.If you need just a single message to be displayed change the return type to `String`.

```
public @ResponseBody String loginUser(request attributes here){

            isUserExisits = service.authenticateUser(userBO);
            if (isUserExisits) {
               return "Login Success";
            } else {
                return "Login Failed";
            }}
```

and On web page you can directly use it.

```
 $(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url : "signin.html",
                type : "post",
                cache: false,
                data : "userName=" +$("#userName").val()+ '&password='+$("#password").val(),
                success : function(data) {

                    var msg = '<span>' + data + '</span>';
                    $('#message').html(msg);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: i have changed my controller, but stil not working. i have alert in success call back which is not working !!!!.

Comment: Does controller code executed successfully? IF yes than what is the error message on browser web console?

Comment: yes the controller code gets executed, and my error callback function is getting called, 'Error in response...'

Comment: put a try catch in your controller code and post the stacktrace I am sure there's an exception in service.authenticateUser(userBO) call.